# How would I use "repeating" to set all 365 x 24 values to 0.0?

Tags: arrays, swift

I need a 2D array: 365 days of the year x 24 hours in the day, with the array cell value being a double.

If I initialise it as:

```
 static var daysHoursArray = [[Double]]()
```

Is this correct and how would I use "repeating" to set all 365 x 24 values to 0.0?

```
static var daysHoursArray = [[Double]](repeating: "0.0", count: 365)
```

I would have thought this would just zero the first column?

And when I have done that how would I update a particular cell? E.g.?

```
let testDouble: Double = 1.0
for days in 0...364 {
        for hours in 0...23 {
            daysHoursArray[days, hours] = testDouble
        }
}
```

There seems to be a lot of examples of 1D arrays but I have found nothing relevant on 2D arrays. Your advice?

Comment: @LeoDabus - FYI - that duplicate only answers half of the OP's question.

Comment: @HangarRash not my downvote. Btw OP is supposed to ask only one question per post

Comment: Apologies - will separate them in future, although they were all closely related - many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest the `repeating` calls:

```
static var daysHoursArray = [[Double]](repeating: Array(repeating: 0.0, count: 24), count: 365)
```

This will give you 365 arrays each containing 24 values of 0.0.

To update a specific value later you can something like:

```
daysHoursArray[day][hour] = value
```

Comment: That explains the required syntax succinctly, thank you.